# SQL Delete Request spend significant time in "Index Delete" even if it affects 0 rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, sqlperformance, sql-delete

I use MSSQL Server 2008 and I have SQL request with simple condition which periodically deletes old records from table (~3 mil records in the table).

This request executed significant time (~ 10 second) even if it affects 0 rows.

This table has some indexes and in Actual Execution Plan I see that "Index Delete" operations consume all execution time.

Why SQL Server does a lot work on indexes if there no any rows affected by delete operation?

Update:

Request:

```
delete t
from Entity t
where t.Revision <= x
AND exists (
    select 1
    from Entity tt
    where tt.Id=t.Id
    and tt.Revision > t.Revision
)
```

Actual execution plan XML: pastebin.com/up2E3iP1

Comment: Perhaps you could provide the query...

Comment: Sorry, sure: 
delete t from Entity t where t.Revision <= x AND exists (select 1 from Entity tt where tt.Id=t.Id and tt.Revision > t.Revision)

Comment: The figures shown in the actual execution plan are percentage of **estimated** cost. Not an indicator of actual execution time. Can you upload the actual execution plan XML somewhere?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/up2E3iP1 there actual execution plan XML

Comment: The execution plan shows that the condition `Revision <= 12586705` doesn't eliminate many rows. Is that typical of the values you will be using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The work is all doing the hash join. All the other costs are bogus.

The actual number of rows coming out of that is `0` but it estimates more.

[image: PLAN]

The costs shown in the rest of the plan are based on the (incorrect) estimates.

You might find this performs better.

```
WITH T AS
(
SELECT *,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Id 
                              ORDER BY Revision DESC) AS RN
FROM Entity
)
DELETE FROM T
WHERE RN > 1
AND Revision <= 12586705
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found joins to be much more performant that subqueries.

Try this

```
delete t
from Entity t
inner join Entity tt ON tt.Id=t.Id
where t.Revision <= x
and tt.Revision > t.Revision
```

Also, ensure you have an index on Id and Revision.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget that even though you aren't going to delete any records SQL still has to check to confirm that there are no records to delete.  Your join between `Entity t` and `Entity tt` has a < in it which is going to require some extra work.  Try running `SET STATISTICS IO ON` in your query window before running the delete.  I'll bet there is a fair amount of IO going on even with the index.  I assume you have an index on `Id, Revision`?  If not you might try adding one.